# How to use LIKE and prepared statements at the same time?

Tags: php, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am creating a bot and the user can enter name of a movie and results should show up by searching inside a SQL table and find the right movies name so I used prepared statements in PDO but I want to when a user type the incomplete name of a movie it shows up so I want it to be case insensitive and also find matches.
I am using mysql dirver.

before this the SQL query was like this

also noting this is a string inside a PHP script

`"SELECT * FROM movies WHERE name = :name LIMIT 5"`

but then I thought to use the way that I explained to you above and I know it isn't case insensitive.

`"SELECT * FROM movies WHERE name LIKE :name" . "'%' LIMIT 5"`

but I don't think this will work properly and fine so how should I write this query to work as I explained at the beginning?

Should use different keywords like `REGEXP` ?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  I removed "regex" because it is not appropriate to the question.

Comment: The question is not about `regexp`.  It is about `like`.  If it is going to be closed as a duplicate, it should be an appropriate duplicate.

Comment: What SQL statement do you want to achieve at the end, pls, show us a sample.

Comment: This question has been reopened under the formal pretext but should be closed as a duplicate

Comment: @YourCommonSense I have done that

Answer (score 2):

Let me assume that you are using MySQL (based on the `regexp` reference).

You can then use:

```
WHERE name LIKE CONCAT(:name, '%')
```

In other databases you can use the standard string concatenation operator, `||`.

Note:  This is often handled at the application level, so `:name` is given the `'%'` in the application.  Then your original code works.

A similar approach would work for a regular expression, but the logic would be:

```
WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('^', :name)
```

Comment: Not sure about PHP, but I typically would use `WHERE name LIKE ?`, and the bind the name concatenated with `%` from the application programming language.  Your version might work too, but I would avoid it.  (Not my downvote, by the way...CommonSense is the likely culprit).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . (1) That is part of the answer.  (2) Named parameters are just fine, often better than unnamed placeholders.

Comment: how can I make it insensitive?

Comment: @GordonLinoff That's not what I'm talking about at all, let me write it another way: `WHERE name LIKE :name` ... in some cases, you might be required to bind the `Gordon%` string value directly to a placeholder.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . " This is often handled at the application level, so :name is given the '%' in the application. "